# disable window task bar on page load asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am developing a application where user requirement to disable window taskbaar after asp.net page load .i am using asp.net with c# .

Please help me

Comment: @Lalit Raghav - I think you want to force your web application to open in FULL screen mode like window application. is it ?

Comment: yes Sir i wants to open full screen mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this task using javascript function as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = maxWindow;

    function maxWindow() {
        window.moveTo(0, 0);


        if (document.all) {
            top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
        }

        else if (document.layers || document.getElementById) {
            if (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < screen.availWidth) {
                top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
                top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

- Put above code in you `.aspx` page in `<head>` tag.

**OR**
you can use **HTML5 API** for FullScreen Mode [Click here](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/)

**Updated Answer**
if above code is not working then try to force "**F11**" key event using below code.

```
function requestFullScreen(element) {

    var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullscreen;

    if (requestMethod) { 
        requestMethod.call(element);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { 
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }
}

var elem = document.body; 
requestFullScreen(elem);
```

Comment: The HTML5 fullscreen mode is almost certainly what you want. Most of those other methods are ignored by most modern browsers due to abuse.